# i am trying to resize the size of my icon based on feature-state using setFeatureState and then using expression in layer. not working

Tags: flutter, mapbox

I am implementing mapbox in a flutter app using mapbox_maps_flutter and i already managed to have my icon layers displayed on the map and when i click on them i get their id which is mentioned in the geojson file i provided when i created the source. i then use that icon id to setFeatureState selected to true. and given a condition in the layer properties that icon size changes given if selected is true or not i was expecting it to work but it isnt. what am i doing wrong?

relevant parts of the code:

```
await _mapboxMap?.setFeatureState(
    'point_source', 'individual_layer', featureId, '{"selected": true}');



Map<String, Object?> layer = {
    "id": "individual_layer",
    "type": "symbol",
    "source": "point_source",
    "layout": {
      'icon-image':
          categoryIconExpression,
      'icon-size': [
        'case',
        [
          'boolean',
          ['feature-state', 'selected'],
          false
        ],
        3, // Set the size to 3 if selected
        1.5, // Set the default size to 1.5
      ],
      'icon-ignore-placement': true,
      'icon-allow-overlap': true, // Allow icon labels to overlap
      'text-field': "{category}",
      'text-size': 12,
      'text-anchor': 'bottom',
      'text-offset': [0, 2],
      //'text-max-width': 8,
      'text-allow-overlap': true,
      'text-ignore-placement': true,
      'text-color': '#FFFFFF', // Set text color to white
    },
    "filter": [
      'all',
      [
        '>',
        ['zoom'],
        5
      ], // Filter to show only when zoom is above 5
      [
        '!',
        ['has', 'point_count']
      ], // Filter to hide clustered icons
    ],
  };
  mapboxMap.style.addStyleLayer(json.encode(layer), null);
```

btw when i getFeatureState it prints out: {"selected":true}